# C trim program isn't working

Tags: c, trim

I am new programmer.
Can you please help me why this C test program isn't working?
It's supposed to be a trim function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 1000

void main(){
    char line[MAX];
    int lgh;
    line[0] = '\0';
    while ((lgh = getLine(line, MAX)) != 0){
        printf("%s", line);
        line[0] = '\0';
    }
}

int getLine(char s[], int length){
    char s2[length];
    int i, ii, qttWord = 0, qttWord2 = 0;
    int c; // c = getchir() d = EOF
    int flag = 2;

    s2[0] = '\0';
    /*Reads the input and puts it into s[], then, verifies if the input is just \n,
    * if so, returns 0(i), if not, puts '\n' at the end of the string ind '\0' to close
    */
    for (i = 0; i < length-1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i){
         s[i] = c;
         ++qttWord;
    }
    if (i == 0){
        if (c == '\n')
            return 0;
    } else if (c == '\n'){
        s[i] = c;
        ++qttWord;
        ++i;
        s[i] = '\0';
    }
    fflush(stdin);
    /*Verifies if the string is just ' ' or '\t'
    * if so, returns 0
    */
    for (i = 0; i <= qttWord && flag != 1; ++i){
        if (s[i] == ' ' || s[i] == '\t'){
            flag = 0;
        } else{
            flag = 1;
        }
    }
    if (flag == 0)
        return 0;
    /*
    *The trim function
    */
    for (i = 0; i < qttWord; ++i){
        if (i < qttWord-1){
            if (s[i] == ' ' && s[i+1] != ' '){
                s2[i] = s[i];
                ++qttWord2;
                printf("1%d\n", s2[i]);//test thing
            }
        }
        if (s[i] != ' '){
            s2[i] = s[i];
            ++qttWord2;
            printf("0%d\n", s2[i]);//test thing
        }
    }
    s[0] = '\0';
    s2[qttWord2+1] = '\0';
    printf("Q:%d\n", qttWord2);//test thing
    printf("A:%s\n", s2);//test thing
    for (i = 0; i < qttWord2+1; ++i){
        s[i] = s2[i];
    }
    return 1;
}
```

As you can see, I created a bunch of printf tests to see why it isn't working, but it's not helping.
I can't understand why it isn't working.

Comment: Um, what is a "trim function" ?

Comment: @LeeTaylor, its a function in which all Leading and trailing whitespace is removed.

Comment: Maybe it's objecting to `void main()`; that isn't a standard definition for `main()`.  And maybe it's objecting to `fflush(stdin);` as that is undefined behaviour, too.  And it is surprising that there isn't a function doing the trimming.  If you're going to mix it with the I/O, then (a) skip leading white space, and (b) don't add the newline since you're going to trim it off.  Also, for diagnosting printing (especially to validate no trailing spaces) use `printf("<<%s>>\n", line);` in the main program.

Comment: And if it's not working, then what is it doing instead?

Comment: Also, you don't have a trim function. You have some code in another function that is labelled as trimming.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, both     void main() and    fflush(stdin) are not undefined...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, sorry I'm new to C programming, what << and >> do?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, when I put a input with a string with 2 ' ' it does not trim the string and also does not show anything.

Comment: ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.21.5.2 *The `fflush` function* _¶2 If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent
operation was not input, the fflush function causes any unwritten data for that stream
to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is
undefined._  C99 and C89 both said much the same thing. You'd have to show the compiler documentation that specifies that `void main()` is defined behaviour; it is at best an implementation-defined alternative way of writing `main()`.

Comment: Inside a format string such as `printf("<<%s>>\n", line);`, the characters `<<` and `>>` represent themselves; they are just convenient marker characters that are relatively unlikely to appear at the start or end of the string you're manipulating, so they make the contents of the string you're manipulating visible, especially trailing blanks or tabs or newlines.  Note that the format string also includes a newline to ensure that the output appears.  You could use `[[` and `]]` or any other characters you regard as distinctive in place of `<<` and `>>`.

Comment: Ok, what would be the correct type of the main()?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler
Ok, what would be the correct type of the main()?

Comment: ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §5.1.2.2.1 _Program startup
¶1 The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no parameters: `int main(void) { /* ... */ }` or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared): `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }` or equivalent; or in some other implementation-defined manner._ C89 did not provide the 'or in some other manner' option, IIRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using rather more standard library functions, notably `fgets()` to read the line, `isspace()` to identify space characters, and `memmove()` to copy the data around, produces this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 1000

static int getLine(char s[], int length);

int main(void)
{
    char line[MAX];
    int lgh;
    /* Stop on EOF or a blank line */
    while ((lgh = getLine(line, MAX)) > 0)
        printf("%d <<%s>>\n", lgh, line);
    return(0);
}

/*
** Get a line of input with leading and trailing white space
** stripped off.  The newline is not included.  If there is no
** newline in the space available, the length 0 is returned.
** If EOF is encountered, EOF is returned.
*/
static int getLine(char s[], int length)
{
    char s2[length];

    s[0] = '\0';
    if (fgets(s2, sizeof(s2), stdin) == 0)
        return EOF;

    size_t len = strlen(s2);
    if (s2[len-1] != '\n')
        return 0;   /* No newline - line too long */

    /* Find first non-white space */
    size_t off = 0;
    while (isspace(s2[off]))
        off++;
    if (off > len)
        return 0;

    /* Chop trailing space */
    while (len-- > 0 && isspace(s2[len]))
        s2[len] = '\0';

    /* Non-blank string is in s2[off]..s2[len], plus trailing '\0' */
    memmove(s, &s2[off], len-off+2);
    return(len - off + 1);  /* Length excluding trailing null */
}
```

Note the diagnostic output in `main()` includes the length reported and also a carefully delimited output string followed by a newline.  Clearly, you can replace `isspace()` with code that strictly checks for blank and tab if you prefer.  You can write your own analogue of `fgets()`.

Your original code didn't like it when it got EOF after the first line of input (I don't think I tried it on an empty input).  Always make sure you handle the degenerate cases gracefully.